# Detecting same value around the borders of a value in 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, logic, multidimensional-array

Let's start with a simple structure:

```
m m N N N
m m N N N
m m N N N
m m m m m
m m m m m
```

How can I detect that the N in the middle has the other Ns surrounded.

So far I have done this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] grid = new char[][]{
                {'m','m','N','N','N'},
                {'m','m','N','N','N'},
                {'m','m','N','N','N'},
                {'m','m','m','m','m'},
                {'m','m','m','m','m'},
        };

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
               if(grid[i][j] == 'N') {
                    //NOW WHAT??
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have iterated over each value of the 2d array but now I am not getting how to do that? :/

**Update:** In respect to your answers, I love them but I want to detect if 'N' makes the squares

Comment: this really doesn't like a question from a user with 3162 scores

Comment: @Topro I scored 3162 by answering mostly web development questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if(grid[i][j] == 'N') {
   if(grid[i-1][j]=='N'&&grid[i+1][j]=='N'&&grid[i][j-1]=='N'&&grid[i][j+1]=='N'&&grid[i-1][j-1]=='N'$$grid[i-1][j+1]=='N'&&grid[i+1][j-1]=='N'&&grid[i+1][j+1]=='N'){
    System.out.println("Key is "+i+","+j)
   }
 }
```

One more thing `your i and j should start with 1` and run `upto < 5-1`

this will give the `key` which is surraounded by `8 N's`

Comment: well... it depends on what the OP considers as surrounded. If the N is in the corner, I assume it needs only three verifications to make sure it is surrounded.

Comment: @user3001267 I want to detect if N makes a square

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui this is surly going to check a square

Comment: @AJ. the if is running only one time :/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you have to do. Check on the same line, below and above of each coordinate.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] grid = new char[][] { { 'm', 'm', 'N', 'N', 'N' }, { 'm', 'm', 'N', 'N', 'N' }, { 'm', 'm', 'N', 'N', 'N' }, { 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm' }, { 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm' }, };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (grid[i][j] == 'N') {
                if (isThisCoordinateSurroundedByCharacter(grid, i, j, 'N')) {
                    System.out.println("Coordinates " + i + "," + j + " are surrounded.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
private static boolean isThisCoordinateSurroundedByCharacter(char[][] grid, int x, int y, char c) {
    // Check above of it.
    if (y > 0) {
        if (grid[x][y - 1] != c) {
            return false;
        }
        if (x > 0 && grid[x - 1][y - 1] != c) { // Check at the left
            return false;
        }
        if (x < grid.length - 1 && grid[x + 1][y - 1] != c) { // Check at
                                                                // the
                                                                // right
            return false;
        }
    }
    // Check in the same line
    if (x > 0 && grid[x - 1][y] != c || x < grid.length - 1 && grid[x + 1][y] != c) {
        return false;
    }
    // Check below
    if (y < grid.length - 1) {
        if (grid[x][y + 1] != c) {
            return false;
        }
        if (x > 0 && grid[x - 1][y + 1] != c) { // Check at the left
            return false;
        }
        if (x < grid.length - 1 && grid[x + 1][y + 1] != c) { // Check at
                                                                // the
                                                                // right
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is the output I got with this code:

```
Coordinates 0,3 are surrounded.
Coordinates 0,4 are surrounded.
Coordinates 1,3 are surrounded.
Coordinates 1,4 are surrounded.
```